# Can I pull a property from a joined table using hibernate rather than the whole object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a java object named task I would like to add a string property named assigneeFullName to, rather than referencing the full user object that it would be pulled from.
Essentially I would like to add something like:

```
private String assigneeFullName;
```

And:

```
<many-to-one name="assigneeFullName" class="string" fetch="select">
    <column name="USER.FULL_NAME join on ASSIGNEE_ID" precision="22" scale="0" />
</many-to-one>
```

or:

```
<property name="assigneeFullName" type="string">
    <column name="DUE_DT" length="7" />
</property>
```

rather than:

```
private User assignee;
```

and:

```
<many-to-one name="assignee" class="User" 
        fetch="select">
<column name="ASSIGNEE_ID" precision="22" scale="0" /> </many-to-one>
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to load the entire `user` object?

Comment: It is, because of tons of restrictions and permissions and other associated data, a very large object, and it seems excessive, when I all I want is the single property.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in a Query using Projection or Constructor Expression in the Select clause.

For example (Projection)

```
select task, user.fullName from ... where ...
```

or (Constructor Expression)

```
select new your.project.Result(task,user.fullName) from ... where ...
```

Where Projection would return a List of `Object[]`, where `[0]` is the Task Entity, and `[1]` is the fullName.

Constructor Expression would return a List of Result (a Class that you would have to implement and that has an appropriate constructor).

Apart from using a Query I don't think that doing such a mapping is possible.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/html/E24396_01/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_constructor) for more Information on Constructor Expressions.